# How to check if one file is empty and another one is not in one condition using bash

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I have 2 files and I want to check if one of them is empty and the other one is not. This is what I have tried writing:

```
if  [ !-s $tmp2 && -s $tmp ];then
```

All I want to check is if tmp is empty and tmp2 is not empty, but whatever I do it doesn't work, sometimes the first condition is always right and sometimes the second one. I have searched the site and did not found any thing that could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reversing the intent. Do this -

```
if [ ! -s "$tmp" ] && [ -s "$tmp2" ]; then
```

**Update**

Make sure you end the `if` statement with `fi`

```
[jaypal~]$ ls tmp* # Checking to see if tmp file exists
tmp2

[jaypal~]$ cat sc.sh 
#!/bin/bash

a=tmp
b=tmp2

if [ ! -s $a ] && [ -s $b ]; then
echo "ok"
fi    # End your if statement with fi

[jaypal~]$ ./sc.sh 
ok # Output confirms that tmp file does not exist and tmp2 exists and has size greater than zero
```

Comment: it is stil not working...
now I get this error:
[: missing ']'
what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

The following should work

```
if [[ ! -s $tmp && -s $tmp2 ]] ; then
   echo "OK"
else
   echo "Not OK"
fi ;
```

-s means file exists and has a size greater than 0

! -s indicates that the file is empty (or does not exist)

So the above checks if **tmp** is **empty** and **tmp2** is **not empty**.

Comment: I'm assuming you have more stuff to add after that line. By itself it won't work! Something like this perhaps   `if [[ ! -s $tmp && -s $tmp2 ]] ; then
  echo "OK"
  else
       echo "Not OK"
  fi ;`

Comment: Also, tmp and tmp2 would have to be defined as well, or replaced with the path to your files.

Comment: You want to explicitly use bash with `[[ ... ]]`. Plain `sh` may not understand it.